# browsing aspx pages and directory accessing for aspx pages via IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted a web application and trying to browse the application, but I am getting errors.

The errors are generating due to file path problems. I searched in google and found some solutions and tried to apply that but still of no use.

I found that there are generally two places of file path, one in `aspx` page and another in `master page` file.
In `aspx` page, the paths are given in `MasterPageFile` and `Inherits`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/content/AdminMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SetStudents.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.content.SetStudents" %>
```

AdminMaster Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="Project.content.AdminMaster" %>
```

My current compiled web app location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iota\content`

1. **Shall I have to change the path of MasterPageFile and Inherits path ?**

I changed the master page file path as `MasterPageFile="./AdminMaster.Master"`.

What would be the Inherits value in this case for aspx page `Inherits="Project.content.SetStudents"` and AdminMaster Page `Inherits="Project.content.AdminMaster"`?

The `Inherits` attribute contains the class for the page and the class file is already compiled with `namespace Project.content`. But when I host the web app I do not have directory as `Project`. So how to resolve this problem?

2. **Should I replace the main folder name Project with iota ?** Also I have many aspx pages, so in all the pages do I have to manually change the path of `MasterPage` file ?

Comment: Can you share what exact error you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The `Inherits` attribute contains the class for the page and the `class` file is already compiled with `namespace Project.content`. But when I host the web app I do not have directory as `Project`. So how to resolve this problem?

Comment: `Project.content` is a namespace, not a folder location for a class. Namespace does not necessarily need to match with the folder structure while it is good to have to avoid such confusion. What namespace is declared in `SetStudents.aspx.cs` file? Also it will be helpful if you can mention the exact error message you are seeing when you run the application.